# how to pass self to Decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

there is a decorator need to pass an object before a function

code is like

```
@mydecorator(someobject):
def myfunc(*args,**kwargs):
    pass
```

this is ok,but when i need to pass the object and use the decorator on the class's method

here's the code,self can't be resolved

```
@mydecorator(self):
def myclassfunc(self,*args,**kwargs):
    pass
```

thou i could write a self version of the decorator, and it works,but it's kinda suck.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `self` like this, because it doesn't even exist at that point. You will have to decorate an instance's `myclassfunc` separately, you can do that inside `__init__`:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myclassfunc = mydecorator(self)(type(self).myclassfunc)

    def myclassfunc(self,*args,**kwargs):
        pass
```

And the decorator creator will be something like this:

```
def mydecorator(ins):
    ins.x = 1 #do something with the instance
    def decorator(old_method):
        def new_method(*args, **kwargs):
            #do something before call
            old_method(ins, *args, **kwargs)
            #do something after call
        return new_method
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time the decorator is applied (class creation time!) `self` doesn't exist yet.

It completely depends on what the decorator is supposed to do.

Be aware that the decorator is applied on the "pure" function, i. e. before instance binding (which is the thing that automatically passes `self`).